# Update stuck at "Setting up keyboard-configuration (1.166ubuntu6) ..."

Tags: updates, keyboard, login

I have a Lenovo Laptop with Ubuntu 17.10 running. When updating (through terminal or Software Updater) the update always gets stuck at:

```
Setting up keyboard-configuration (1.166ubuntu6) ...
```

I waited about one hour but nothing happens. When I kill the update process I can't login anymore after rebooting. The Login Screen appears again after pressing LogIn. And I can't use the Terminal Login with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> because there is only the blinking cursor.

Does anyone have a clue what is going on?

I already put an old image on my Laptop but it is now stuck at the same position again...

Comment: I managed to kill the update process. But running 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' afterwarts stucks at the same point..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't really have a clue of what's going on, but as as stopgap fix I edited `/var/lib/dpkg/info/keyboard-configuration.postinst` and `/var/lib/dpkg/info/console-setup.postinst` and put `exit 0` aftert the `#!/bin/sh`line.
This at least allowed `apt --fix-broken install` to 'fix' it and lets me install other packages.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get it thru like this: Check child processes of apt/dpkg, and kill "plymouth --ping"(there may be other such processes that are not related, don't kill them). Repeat as many times as it seems to hang. Likely two, one for console-setup-linux and another for keyboard-configuration.

Edit:
Here's a bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/1715830 that you can vote up. It's marked as duplicate with similar hang on kernel update. Not sure if they're really duplicate thou.

DON'T bother to try to "systemctl restart plymouth", it will restart your GUI session and if I understood, also text console sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalled plymouth, now keyboard-configuration runs like a charm.